# how to disable random: crng init done

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, archlinux, xilinx, interrupt-handling

I am working on ZCU-102  and booted a linux kernel succesfully.I had wrote a driver for our device connected over Zcu102 board. The driver is loaded succssfully. The driver have interrupt handler , while serving a ISR getting the below log : random: crng init done
During this log time , Interrupt handler is not calling (handler is not handled )

Can you please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Does your ISR use some `crng`, possibly implicitly initializing it?

Comment: No ISR is not using crng Actually , when I run an application which give an interrupt to driver , which count how many times a engine will trigger.